# Best way to See if String in Hashset contains elements from another hashset? C#

Tags: c#

I  have a hashset of strings that contain lognames called pidLogsLines. From this hashset I want to filter out logs that only contain strings from another hashset called pidList and put these logs inside a new hashset called filesWithPid. I am doing this with two loops:

```
var filesWithPid = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
foreach(var logname in pidLogsLines)
{
    foreach(var pid in pidList)
    {
        if (logname.Contains(pid))
        {
            filesWithPid.Add(logname);
        }
    }

}
```

Is this the optimal way to do it? I am new to C# so I am not aware of any elaborate faster ways to do it

Comment: Honestly, a HashSet doesn't provide any benefit here.

Comment: @Llama This logic is actually part of a bigger application and the application uses these hashsets. The hashsets are used for filtering up to this logic so yeah thats why I am using them

Comment: How many elements are each HashSet and are they ordered? Depending on size and ordering, you may want to opt for a binary search. Otherwise, this seems to be standard.

Comment: The hashset pidLogsLines can have 50000 items (lognames) but the second hashset pidList  will only have at most 200 items (PIDs). No they are not ordered @Hayden

Comment: I think it's a problem that can be parallelized.  You could use multiple threads to scan through multiple hash sets in parallel.  While visiting each item, add the string to a shared concurrent (thread safe) dictionary.  At the end, you'd have a data structure which only contains the shared items you're looking for.  I think the code you have above, though, is the *simplest* way to do it, so be sure you're not prematurely optimizing things that don't need to be that complex.

Comment: I agree with Mike. If this meets your performance requirements then I'd say leave it as is. If you needed more performance and can spare more memory usage, I'd say converting them to lists would be more efficient to loop over. Then on top of that you can also do multithreading if even more performance is needed. I can provide a simple example on this is needed.

Comment: @MikeChristensen yeah I agree. I looked at the "LINQ" solution linked and syntactically due to my being new to LINQ, I have no idea what I am looking at. So I will stick to the standard way I did it. Thanks guys. But I need to learn LINQ